# How to generate a random number between two values then set to TextView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, random

How to generate a random number between two values and then set to TextView?

```
        int min = 1;
        int max = 100;
        Random r1 = new Random();
        int random = r1.nextInt(max - min) + min;                       
        tv1.setText(""+random);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
int value = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
num1.setText(value+"");
```

You can't use .setText(value), because integer will be a resource link to /res/strings! **Add +"" after number!!!**

There are two (or more) methods:
public final void setText (CharSequence text) - To set text
public final void setText (int resid) - to set text from file /res/string/strings.xml

Comment: I do it
but my Activity does not Start and seen this massage in console 


(Info)Skipped 959 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Why you use startActivity()? Remove it!

Comment: I replace my code. please look to my Question again

Comment: Hmm... What is b.get("from")? Can you replace it will any number, for example "5" and "9"?

Answer (score 2):

```
Random random = new Random();
int value = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
num1.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

barwnikk was almost right, but shouldn't be doing that kind of tricks in order to convert from int to String

Comment: It's same as my answer, but I'm first :D

Comment: Almost, but I consider mine a bit more correct. That's why I answered and specifically mentioned you. Hope you don't mind the little "correction" (even if it was not incorrect, per se).

Comment: It isn't mind :) It working same as +"". There are others solutions. You can also do it with Integer.valueOf(value).toString().

Comment: wow, you chose a long one, indeed. I'll throw in another one (I go more simple), so we can add it to the collection: Integer.toString(value)

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of answers. What about BigDecimal.valueOf(value).toString()?

Comment: Oh, that's a cheap trick. You can go the same way with long, float,...That doesn't count as a point; more like a mini-point, maybe :)

Comment: Oh, oh. I was suspicious, so I checked. It turns out that your BigDecimal proposition won't work. That "valueOf(int)" doesn't exist. My counter-propositions would work with an extra cast to long/float, but a trailing ".0" would be added. So we would have to remove your mini-point, and convert my two mini-points to mini-mini-points XD

Comment: You can also send integer to server using DataOutputStream and read string, hahaha :D

Comment: hahaha!
I was thinking about writing it into a file, putting that file in a sdcard and giving the sdcard to a pigeon. The pigeon could bring it to my home, Ii could read it, text you the value in a sms, and you could create a new variable holding the string. Then, it would be as simple as getting the string in a sdcard, pigeon, and back to the user. At very least, it would be a worldwide know Customer Service. We could get to be famous!

Answer (score -1):

This is how to generate a number between two numbers but i don't know how to set to text view

```
 Random r = new Random();
 int value;
 value = r.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

Comment: Tanx .I used This Code . But My Activity is Force Closed   :(

Comment: Because you can't set integer as .setText Look for my answer.

Comment: barwnikk      
 
 num11.setText(random1);
       
 num22.setText(random2);

Comment: Not. It doesn't never working. You must add +"" after integer. Look below for my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea about how to set to text view. i am just giving my advice on how to do random number between two integers. don't give me hate, you can look at barwnikk's answer above